# Right to refuse service without explanation

Tags: united-states, civil-rights, discrimination

I have a question regarding the right to refuse service.  Can you be refused from a store **without an explanation**?

I went to my local Family Dollar and the assistant manager rudely told me, "Umm excuse me, you're not allowed in here." I asked her why, and she just said, "I have the right to refuse anyone I want to."

Comment: This is a question about legal advise. It does not belong here. But it would be on-topic on https://law.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

It appears that there's no stipulation in any laws that there has to be a verbal explanation as to why they are refusing you service. The law addresses other aspects of it, however. Here's an article on LegalZoom that covers it fairly well: https://www.legalzoom.com/articles/the-right-to-refuse-service-can-a-business-refuse-service-to-someone-because-of-appearance

What's important is that:

- the establishment may not refuse service due to a person belonging to a protected class (at a federal level: race, color, religion or national origin [Civil Rights Act] or having a disability [Americans with Disabilities Act]; at a state level: several states also include one's sexual orientation as a protected class)
- the establishment may not refuse service to individuals arbitrarily, but have a policy that can be applied consistently to all people.

So they must have a valid reason, but they don't necessarily need to explain it voluntarily. However, if you don't feel they have a valid reason, then you should ask. And if they don't answer, then you may want to get yourself advice from a lawyer. You may have a case.

UPDATE:

Avi pointed out that it appears that the 'non-arbitrariness' is conditional on being a protected class. Another article makes it a bit clearer that there isn't a direct connection and that the non-arbitrariness appears to be 'in general'. If you are going to refuse service to someone, it must be based on a reason consistently applied to all (emphasis mine):

> While the right to refuse service is not a get out of jail free card allowing businesses to turn away people they don’t want to serve, there are some valid reasons for asking customers to leave. Individuals or groups who are causing trouble or being disruptive may be asked to leave, while restaurants or other businesses with a capacity limit can turn away customers to prevent this limit from being exceeded. Businesses can also refuse service to those who come in just before closing time or to those who are not making any purchases during their visit. There are various other examples – *the key thing to note is that in each example, the decision to refuse service is not arbitrary* ***or*** based upon an individual’s specific characteristics.

source: http://www.business2community.com/trends-news/right-refuse-service-businesses-discrimination-0766551#omw9m1vLCRPEgdXS.99

Comment: I was working on an answer based on that article, but I hadn't had a chance to finish writing it up.  This is much more succinct than I would have been. +1.

Comment: @DA The legalzoom article doesn't say that a restaurant can't refuse service arbitrarily, it says that they can't arbitrarily discriminate against members of a protected class.

Comment: @avi maybe I'm misreading the article, but it seems clear to me. "To avoid being arbitrary, there must be a reason for refusing service and you must be consistent"

Comment: @DA The preceding sentence is "The answer is that you can refuse to serve someone even if they’re in a protected group, but the refusal can’t be arbitrary and you can’t apply it to just one group of people", so the require for non-arbitrariness is referring to the instance in which the person is a member of a protected class.

Comment: @Avi let me try to find more clarification out in the wild. I see what you're saying. It seems open to interpretation.

Answer (score -2):

There are some grounds for refusal of service that are not legal. The [Civil Rights Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Rights_Act_of_1964) prohibits discrimination on the basis of race, religion, or national origin in restaurants or hotels or other public accommodations. Furthermore, a number of states have laws prohibiting discrimination on the basis of [sexual orientation or gender identity](https://www.aclu.org/map/non-discrimination-laws-state-state-information-map).

Comment: -1 - the question asked if there's a right to refuse sans explanation, not a right to refuse on specific explanation. E.g., whether CRA implies that service can't be refused at all without showing proof that you're not refusing for CRA reasons upfront.

Comment: @DVK The burden of proof would be on the plaintiff to show that the refusal of service is discriminatory, yeah. would this be improved if I added a line saying that there is no prohibition against refusal of service for any or no reason so long as it isn't discriminatory?

Comment: if you can provide evidence for that, absolutely improved

Comment: @DVK I think that's kind of proving a negative? What evidence would I provide to show that there is no prohibition on arbitrary refusal of service.

Comment: a court opinion would clearly work

Comment: @DVK I don't know that there's been one. You seem to be requesting I prove a negative, or interpreting OP's quesiton in that light

Comment: This doesn't address the question.